# How to show that T is invertible in this case.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inverse

> Let $T$ be a linear transformation from a vector space $V$ over reals into $V$ such that $T-T^2=I.$  Show that $T$ is invertible.

I am not able to understand how is $T$ being treated like a matrix when it is infact a linear transformation.

Is it the Matrix equivalent of $T$ being talked about?

Comment: Linear transformations, matrices, functions, operators, ... One of the big points of *linear algebra* is to understand that we can still *use algebra* with these and even more exotic objects to some degree.

Comment: Please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of pasting images, which are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. I find it hard to imagine that taking the picture, cropping it, uploading it and then linking to it was less effort than typing in those two sentences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $T$ is a linear transformation, $T^2$ means $T\circ T$. And$$T-T^2=\operatorname{Id}\iff T\circ(\operatorname{Id}-T)=\operatorname{Id}.$$Therefore, $T$ is invertible and $T^{-1}=\operatorname{Id}-T$.